# zeep: No schema available for the namespace 'urn:WebdialerSoap'

Tags: python, xml, soap, xml-namespaces, zeep

I'm trying to get a list of devices associated with the specified end-user with SOAP from Cisco CUCM 10.5.2 (i.e., [getProfileSoap](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/webdialer/#!webdialer-developer-guide/-lt-getprofilesoap-gt)). I'm using zeep to handle requests and responses.
I call such an endpoint this way:

```
service.getProfileSoap(in0={"userID": "foo", "password": "bar"}, in1="just_a_username")
```

but I get:

> zeep.exceptions.NamespaceError: Unable to resolve type
> {urn:WebdialerSoap}WDDeviceInfo. No schema available for the namespace
> 'urn:WebdialerSoap'.

Responses are like the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:getProfileSoapResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="urn:WD70">
         <getProfileSoapReturn href="#id0"/>
      </ns1:getProfileSoapResponse>
      <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:GetConfigResponse" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:WD70">
         <description xsi:type="xsd:string">Success</description>
         <deviceInfoList soapenc:arrayType="ns3:WDDeviceInfo[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:ns3="urn:WebdialerSoap">
            <item href="#id1"/>
         </deviceInfoList>
         <responseCode href="#id2"/>
      </multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:int" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">0</multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns4:WDDeviceInfo" xmlns:ns4="urn:WebdialerSoap" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <deviceName xsi:type="xsd:string">IPCMRAEU5UCM5X7</deviceName>
         <lines soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
            <item xsi:type="xsd:string">1251 ; no partition</item>
         </lines>
      </multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It looks like a problem with the XML schema. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Do you  have a schema for WD7.xsd?

Comment: No I have not. I have just the main WSDL, that is quite similar to [this one](https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/webdialer-java-sample/blob/master/schema/wd70.wsdl)

Comment: There are a few things I think need modifications.  First the response you are getting may have errors.  I do not like the namespaces with "ns1".  The definition for ns1 is missing which make the xml invalid.  The people who created the xml need to be notified and fix this serious error.  A schema check should always be performed by the people who generate an xml and not by the people who receive the bad file.

Comment: I see. Thanx for pointing this out. I've already notified the problem. In the meanwhile. any workaround to use zeep with those responses? (e.g., manually adding the missing namespace)

Comment: The only way is to manually modify the response and add the missing namespace.  Can you test by reading a file instead of the response stream?

Comment: Yes, eventually I can also get and process the raw response but I'm gonna loose the layer of abstraction provided by zeep.

Comment: The only way of eliminating the error is to fix he namespace.